# Problems with array of pointers to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

After defining the type student (which is a struct made of two arrays of characters and an int), I've created an array of pointers to student, which I need in order to modify its content inside of a series of functions.

```
int main(void) 
{
    student* students[NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS];

    strcpy(students[0]->name, "test");
    strcpy(students[0]->surname, "test");
    students[0]->grade = 18;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My problem is that this simple piece of code returns -1 as exit status after running. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers are pointing to nowhere since you have not allocated any memory for them to point to.

```
int main(void) 
{
    student* students = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student)*[NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS]); \\malloc dynamically allocate heap memory during runtime

strcpy(students[0]->name, "test");
strcpy(students[0]->surname, "test");
students[0]->grade = 18;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

*Note Edit by [marko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450758/marko) -- Strictly the pointers are pointing to whatever was last in the stack location or register holding it - it may be nothing, or something you actually care about. The joys of UB

Comment: Strictly the pointers are pointing to whatever was last in the stack location or register holding it  - it may be nothing, or something you actually care about.  The joys of UB

Answer (score 3):

The pointer `students[0]` is uninitialized. Dereferencing it results in undefined behavior.

Initialize it with the address of a valid object before attempting to access it.

```
student test;
students[0] = &test;

strcpy(students[0]->name, "test");
strcpy(students[0]->surname, "test");
students[0]->grade = 18;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it is UB. You have only pointer without the actual structs allocated.

```
students[x] = malloc(sizeof(*students[0]));
```

or statically

```
student s;
students[x] = &s;
```

or

```
 students[x] = &(student){.name = "test", .surname ="test", .grade = 18};
```